# Custom tag workers in iText C#

Tags: c#, itext

I want to change some content on my HTML and dynamically change it on C#. I've seen this doc and read https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-5-custom-tag-workers-and-css-appliers but I couldn't work it out since I am new to programming and has 0 knowledge in JAVA. Any idea how to do this in C#?

Here's the code from iText doc:

```
String[] names = {"Bruno Lowagie", "Ingeborg Willaert", "John Doe"};
int counter = 1;
for (String name : names) {
    app.createPdf(name, SRC, String.format(DEST, counter++));
}

public void createPdf(String name, String src, String dest) throws IOException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
    converterProperties.setTagWorkerFactory(
        new DefaultTagWorkerFactory() {
            @Override
            public ITagWorker getCustomTagWorker(
                IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context) {
                if ("name".equalsIgnoreCase(tag.name()) ) {
                    return new SpanTagWorker(tag, context) {
                        @Override
                        public boolean processContent(
                            String content, ProcessorContext context) {
                            return super.processContent(name, context);
                        }
                    };
                }
                else if ("date".equalsIgnoreCase(tag.name()) ) {
                    return new SpanTagWorker(tag, context) {
                        @Override
                        public boolean processContent(
                            String content, ProcessorContext context) {
                            return super.processContent(
                                sdf.format(new Date()), context);
                        }
                    };
                }
                return null;
            }
        } );
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(src), new File(dest), converterProperties);
}
```

Comment: *"I want to change some content on my HTML"* - you are aware that itext is a pdf creation and manipulation library and only uses html as a possible source format. If you want to manipulate html files, you should look for other APIs...

Comment: ABCpdf could be an option. The latest version (11) uses a customised version of the Chrome/Blink HTML rendering engine that enables you to attach your own JavaScript to a page and await the script completion prior to rendering to PDF. Gecko (Firefox) and IE engines are also available with similar functionality but I prefer the ABCChrome engine. More details here: https://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-9.aspx.

Comment: @mics please, could you explain a bit more what you want to achieve. Could you give any example with the source html/pdf and the expected result?